# Not able to boot to arch because of acpi bios error

Tags: linux, arch-linux, acpi, bios

As the topic says I am not been able to boot to my arch. It shows some acpi bios error. I am attaching the image of it.
[image]

It may happen due to xf86-input-mtrack I installed from AUR package. After that I followed  this tutorial "https://howchoo.com/g/mdy0ngziogm/the-perfect-almost-touchpad-settings-on-linux-2" from second point. And then I used this command in terminal

> `sudo systemd restart gdm.service`

, as much as I can remember. After that screen flashes for long time , so I force shut down my laptop. From then it is giving this problem. 
Though it used to show these ACPI errors before, but I was able to boot into the OS.

Comment: If you are sure its from xf86-input-mtrack , Boot from a Arch Live,  chroot and undo what ever you have done, and reboot.